# What is best Option to store Access Token, Refresh tokens?

Tags: apex, integration, callout, apexrest

- Platform cache : 
  I am using platform cache but platform cache is not returning anything after very small period of time ( approx 30 sec- 60 sec ).
- Custom Setting : Custom setting has a limitation of fields can be created max 255 character. Access tokens are more than that.
- Custom Object : Custom Object won't be good solution i think considering it's sensitive data.
- Custom Metadata : I am not sure.

Any Idea what would be the best approach?

Comment: Are you working in a managed package context?

Comment: Nope, I am not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If possible, use [Named Credentials](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=named_credentials_about.htm&type=0). You don't need to manage the Access Tokens or Refresh Tokens at all, as the platform does it for you, and securely stores the tokens in a way that's non-trivial to retrieve, even for administrators. Also, feel free to read [Secure Coding: Storing Secrets](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Secure_Coding_Storing_Secrets) for other alternatives. Custom Metadata Types is also a viable solution.

Comment: Thank You for providing all the valuable information. I have implemented Named credentials for username password but not for oAuth2.0.  I will go through the attached links to resolve the issue.